# Update row of a table with nickname as primary key

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql

[image]

When I try with Spring to udpdate the user with different values, but, for example, without modifying nickname:

```
//TODO: encripta contraseña monitorDao
public void updateMonitor(Monitor monitor){
    BasicPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new BasicPasswordEncryptor(); 
    String contrasenya = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(monitor.getContrasenya());
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
            "update Usuario set nickname=?, nombre= ?, apellidos= ?, email= ?, contrasenya = ?, especialidades = ?, telefono = ?", 
            monitor.getNickname(), monitor.getNombre(), monitor.getApellidos(), monitor.getEmail(), 
            contrasenya, monitor.getEspecialidades(), monitor.getTelefono()
            );
}
```

This happens:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [update Usuario set nickname=?, nombre=
>   ?, apellidos= ?, email= ?, contrasenya = ?, especialidades = ?,
>   telefono = ?]; ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "pk_usuario"

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. Post (formatted) text. Even better post the entire `create table` statement - that makes it easier for anyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used JDBC templates but it looks like you don't have a where clause in your SQL so you're updating all rows in the database to have those values. You need to restrict it to a single user by adding a where clause:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update(
        "update Usuario set nickname=?, nombre= ?, apellidos= ?, email= ?, contrasenya = ?, especialidades = ?, telefono = ? where nickname=?", 
        monitor.getNickname(), monitor.getNombre(), monitor.getApellidos(), monitor.getEmail(), 
        contrasenya, monitor.getEspecialidades(), monitor.getTelefono(), monitor.getNickname()
        );
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-examples-update

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try this:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update(
    "update Usuario set nombre= ?, apellidos= ?, email= ?, contrasenya = ?, especialidades = ?, telefono = ? where nickname=?", 
   monitor.getNombre(), monitor.getApellidos(), monitor.getEmail(), 
    contrasenya, monitor.getEspecialidades(), monitor.getTelefono(), monitor.getNickname()
    );
```

This won't update the nickname.